# Suitable spacing in multiple choices

Tags: enumitem

I'm preparing some test questions using `enumitem` package. MWE I found and slightly modified from 4-years old question here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newlist{choices}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[choices]{label*=(\Alph*)}
\newcommand{\choice}{\item}

\SetEnumitemKey{twocol}{
  before=\raggedcolumns\begin{multicols}{2},
  after=\end{multicols}}

\SetEnumitemKey{threecol}{
  before=\raggedcolumns\begin{multicols}{3},
  after=\end{multicols}}

\begin{document}
Which fractions are reduced (one column)?
\begin{choices}
  \choice long answer long answer long answer
   \choice $\dfrac{8}{24}$
   \choice $\dfrac{44}{121}$
   \choice $\dfrac{9}{11}$
\end{choices}

Which fractions are reduced (two columns)?
\begin{choices}[twocol]
   \choice long answer  long answer  long answer
   \choice $\dfrac{8}{24}$
   \choice $\dfrac{44}{121}$
   \choice $\dfrac{9}{11}$
\end{choices}

Which fractions are reduced (three columns)?
\begin{choices}[threecol]
   \choice long answer  long answer  long answer
   \choice $\dfrac{8}{24}$
   \choice $\dfrac{44}{121}$
\end{choices}

\end{document}
```

My question is - How to get columns of suitable width? The long long answer should not be broken. I've read the manual to `enumitem`, still have no ideas. Please, any suggestions??

Comment: I think, the `tasks` package is more suited for such column like item/choices

Comment: Probably yes. Could anybody give the suitable link?

Comment: Hi, Christian;-) Unfortunately I cant use tasks, it seems some my computer problem. So I decided to keep enumitem package.